# Getting HTTP Response code 500 for posting on localhost

Tags: java, http-post, http-get

I don't know how to POST things on a localhost webserver. I don't even know how to make the webserver handle POST requests. I tried the following code and manage to post on an API but have not been able to do the same on my localhost.

```
 public class JSONTest {
   public static String executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters){
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
    try {
      //Create connection
      url = new URL(targetURL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
      connection.setUseCaches (false);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      //Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
      wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
      wr.flush ();
      wr.close ();

      //Get Response    
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      return response.toString();
    }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;

    }
    finally {
      if(connection != null)
        connection.disconnect(); 
    }       
}
 public static String test(){
    try{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    //JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    obj.put("Products","Successful test");
    return "Products="+obj.toString();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String[]args){
   executePost("http://<localhost>:9000/SelendroidManager",test());
}
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://<localhost>:9000/SelendroidManager
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at Administrator.JSONTest.executePost(JSONTest.java:65)
at Administrator.JSONTest.main(JSONTest.java:144)
```

The log output of the server is :

```
 Reapplying settings...
 Set current project to lol (in build file:/C:/Users/eedcoro/activator-1.2.2-minimal/lol/)
 Reapplying settings...
 Set current project to lol (in build file:/C:/Users/eedcoro/activator-1.2.2-minimal/lol/)
 Running task... Cancel: sbt.TaskCancellationStrategy$Null$@7b6bbeaf, check cycles: false
 Initial source changes: removed:Set() added: Set() modified: Set() Removed products: Set() External API changes: API Changes: Set() Modified binary dependencies: Set() Initial directly invalidated sources: Set() Sources indirectly invalidated by: product: Set() binary dep: Set() external source: Set()
 All initially invalidated sources: Set()
 Discovered main classes:
 Got auto-discovered main classes, looking for a default mainClass setting if any
 launching mainClass task
 Set current project to lol (in build file:/C:/Users/eedcoro/activator-1.2.2-minimal/lol/)
 > listen
 Reapplying settings...
 Set current project to lol (in build file:/C:/Users/eedcoro/activator-1.2.2-minimal/lol/)
 Reapplying settings...
 Set current project to lol (in build file:/C:/Users/eedcoro/activator-1.2.2-minimal/lol/)
 Running task... Cancel: sbt.TaskCancellationStrategy$Null$@7b6bbeaf, check cycles: false
 Default main class is 'play.core.server.NettyServer'
```

Comment: is it really `<localhost>` or `localhost` ?

Comment: It is actually 140.XXX.XXX.XX but i changed it to localhost so you guys understand the general idea.

Comment: what does the server log say ?

Comment: I am using play-framework so I don't know if the log output will be very useful. I updated the post so you can see the log output

Comment: what happens if you make a GET to same url from your web browser ?

Comment: What do you mean? And maybe this helps, but the URL actually works on the browser... I just can't seem to get access to it.

Comment: oh wait you are POSTing something to server, inspect the raw request it sends to server and troubleshoot what is being passed in wrong also put some logging at server side which helps you trace request

Comment: Ok. According to eclipse, I get an error exactly when I call : InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

Comment: 500 is being returned from your server

Comment: So I should be fixing the way the webServer receives the POST requests from the java program?

Comment: server isn't happy with request, so _inspect the raw request it sends to server and troubleshoot what is being passed in wrong also put some logging at server side which helps you trace request_